# Does there exist a function which satisfies follow conditions?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does there exist a function which satisfies following conditions?

1) $F(x)=\frac{G(x)}{H(x)}$ is a sigmoid function (or S-shaped function);

2) $G(x)$ is strictly concave;

3) $H(x)$ is not a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

G(x) = log(x+1)

H(x) = 1+log(x+1)

F(x) = log(x+1)/(1+log(x+1))

That works grand

edit: you edited your question. Your new answer is

H = log(x+1)/(tanh(x+4)+1)

G = log(x+1)

F = tanh(x+4)+1

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But I can't fully understand the functions you offered. The first function, referred to as $F1$, indeed works when $x \in [0,\infty]$, which I can understand. But the second one, $F2=1/(tanh(x+4)+1)$, is this a sigmoid function?

Comment: Yep, I had a typo in there, basically F can be any sigmoid function you like, just make G  random concave function, and H the inverse of a sigmoid times G

Comment: Cool, man! I get it! I will try to work as you said, it's a nice method.